# Как подключить css,js,картинки к node.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, изображения

Здравствуйте,у меня проблема : Пытаюсь подключить css, js файлы и картинки к node.js  с помощью require , но он выдает ошибку при чтении css / js файлов (менял местами).Если запускать сам html файл,то он все работает. Как подключить картинки? (Чтобы он их читал и выводил на сайт). Как сделать так,чтобы он читал и применял к сайту css и js?

[image: Не читает css и js файлы]

Comment: А зачем вам css в js файле напрямую? Html файл должен ссылаться на какую то публичную папку, а там должны лежать ваши css и картинки. До тех пор, пока ваш js не должен взаимодействовать с ними, им там не место вообще.

Comment: Читает. Просто для удобства делают небольшое разделение по папкам. Например: 
Build (рутовая папка для юая)
  index.html (наш индекс файл с которого все начинается)
  Imgs (папка для картинок)
  Fonts (папка для шрифтов)
  Styles (папка для стилей)

Comment: Переместил все по папкам,какие либо изменения в коде делать нужно? Ибо путь переписал,а проблема осталась.

Comment: Как вы подключаете файлы в html? Вот это должно работать: <img src="./img/MY_IMAGE.jpg"  />

Comment: Так и подключаю,не помогает. 
<img src="./img/images.jpg" id="Pic">

Comment: html лежит правильно? под ним есть папка img? Открываете страничку в хроме, смотрите какие ошибки в секции нетворк и консоли. Если картинка не подгрузилась там будет ошибка и путь по которой он пытался вытащить картинку. Проверяете путь.

Comment: Да,правильно. Ошибок он не выдает,но и на сайте не показывает

Comment: Правильно. Я не подумал что вы стартуете index с помощью node  а просто открываете его. Простите.

Comment: Ничего,спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

По умолчанию Node JS сервер **не отдает статические файлы** в браузер по запросам.
Вы можете самим писать сервак, отдающий статические файлы по запросу или использовать модуль Express. Создайте папку (да-да, каталог) /public в корне, поместите в неё папки (каталоги) с css и js-файлами, картинки и прочие публичные ресурсы:

```
var path = require('path');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

Теперь по запросу `127.0.0.1/main.css` экспресс пороется в публичной папке и, если найдёт, то отправит вам стили.

Comment: Выдает такую ошибку,что делать?
ReferenceError: path is not defined

Comment: Исправил. Точно, путь же ещё надо указать. Вместо вас найти путь может модуль path. Ещё одна зависимость, такой вот node js. Кстати, модуль полезен не только для выдачи статики. Он укажет путь для работы с файлами fs, для upload с форм на сайте (если надо будет прикрепить картинку).

Comment: К сожалению проблемы это не решило. Сайт все такая-же голая html.Хотя ошибок больше не выдает.

Comment: проверьте консоль браузера и сервака, пути к стилям в браузере и на серваке